# How to disable HTML mode in Emacs?

Tags: html, emacs

I want to use web-mode as my major mode for my web development needs but HTML mode is always there instead of web-mode. So is there any way to disable HTML mode in emacs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add html to the list of files to use `web-mode` with. You can do this by adding the following line to your `init.el` file

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html?\\'" . web-mode))
```